# example dataset trying to query by name

Tags: neo4j

I am trying out neo4j and I downloaded and successfully configured the example dataset `cineasts_39_movies_446_actors.zip` from [here](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/example_data)

I can query node 1 fine:

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ START n=node(1) RETURN n
==> +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
==> | n                                                                                                                                                          |
==> +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
==> | Node[1]{login:"micha",roles:["ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_USER"],name:"Micha",password:"339f455efd4af00b3e62385f3b7ef694",__type__:"org.neo4j.cineasts.domain.User"} |
==> +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I query nodes with name Micha?  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
start n=node:User("login:micha") return n;
```

The syntax for index lookups is like so:

```
<node/relationship>:<index name>(<lucene query/shorthand single field lookup>)
```

The shorthand looks like this, and makes it easier to parameterize:

```
start n=node:User(login="micha") return n;
```

And parameterized in JSON like so:

```
{query:"start n=node:User(login={username}) return n;", params:{username:"micha"}}
```

Comment: sorry new to neo4j but got `MissingIndexException: Index `Users` does not exist`

Comment: Hmm, I thought that was how it was bundled. Hang on let me check here.

Comment: It was named `User` instead of `Users`. This is how you can check for indexes in the shell: https://gist.github.com/wfreeman/5112532